# Trying to append values to a numpy array of vector features

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, logistic-regression

I have a set of feature vectors for sentences I have obtained using:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as trainingSentences:
    sentence2region2value = json.loads(trainingSentences.read())

train_wordlist = []

for sentence,locations in sentence2region2value.iteritems():
      train_wordlist.append(" ".join(sentence_to_words(sentence, True)))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   \
                             tokenizer = None,    \
                             preprocessor = None, \
                             stop_words = None,   \
                             max_features = 5000)

train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_wordlist)

train_data_features = train_data_features.toarray()
```

I want to also add the label for all of these 492 feature vectors for a logistic regression. This "prediction" label is contained in the `sentence2region2value` dictionary:

```
{sentence: Y
   {parsedsentence: Z
        {prediction: X,
             location-values:{"Qatar": [32,221,31]},{"Dubai": [12,123,421]},.....}
```

Currently I am trying to use this:

```
for prediction in sentence2region2value["sentence"]["parsedsentence"].iteritems():
      for i in train_data_features:
            train_data_features[i] = np.append(train_data_features[i],np.array(prediction))
```

But it isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem expression isn't very readable, and I have to guess at what some variables look like, but I'll comment on it:

```
for prediction in sentence2region2value["sentence"]["parsedsentence"].iteritems():
```

So `prediction` will be a pair of values, `(key, value)`, from that dictionary.  I'm guessing it would be something like `("Qatar", [32,221,31])`, but I'm not sure you are working down that far in the dictinary.

```
      for i in train_data_features:
```

`train_data_features` is an array (from the previous `toarray()` expression), but I don't know what it contains (shape and dtype?).  I'm guessing strings, maybe just objects (pointers to objects, like a list).

In any case `i` is one of those elements.  But then why do `train_data_features[i]`?  That only makes sense if `i` is a number, the result of `for i in range(train_data_features.shape[0]):`

Lets assume that's really what `i` is, so that `train_data_features[i]` is actually an element of that array.

```
            train_data_features[i] = np.append(train_data_features[i], np.array(prediction))
```

This `np.append` would work if that element is itself is an array.

But what does `np.array(prediction)` look like?

This might work:

y=np.array(('quatar',[1,2,3]), dtype=object)

and if `train_data_features[i]` is similar, then append would do something like

```
In [220]: x
Out[220]: array(['quatar', [1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)

In [221]: x=np.append(x,y)

In [222]: x
Out[222]: array(['quatar', [1, 2, 3], 'quatar', [1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)

In [223]: x=np.append(x,y)

In [224]: x
Out[224]: array(['quatar', [1, 2, 3], 'quatar', [1, 2, 3], 'quatar', [1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

You haven't given us a good idea of what the variable contain, or what you intend this expression to do.  But may be my floundering around will help you work out the details.

I encourage you to test the code piece by piece in an interactive session, like I am doing here.   Don't just write a big expression, and hope it runs.  Develop it piece by piece, and make sure each addition works as expected.

And either edit the question, or expect more negative votes and/or close votes.